# Does PHP have an ordered dictionary?

Tags: php, data-structures

Does PHP have an Ordered Dictionary, like that in [Python](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)? IE, each key value pair additionally has an ordinal associated with it.

Comment: AFAIK, no but would love to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how PHP arrays work out of the box. Each key/value pair has an ordinal number, so the insertion order is remembered. You can easily test it yourself:

http://ideone.com/sXfeI

Comment: Ah, but can you, say, insert an element before another element without deleting/re-appending elements *en masse*?

Comment: Unfortunately no. To do something like you'd have to keep an numeric indexed array, so you can use functions like `array_splice` to insert at random offsets. And if you also need to be able to access the elements through a dictionary key, you'll probably need some sort of a mapping array, that maps dict keys to their corresponding values in the indexed array.

Comment: The link provided no more has a solution

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the description in the python docs correctly, then yes. 
PHP Arrays are actually only ordered maps:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

[PHP Array docs](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: What happens when you insert a key that already exists? It seems to leave the key in place, but is that guaranteed? http://ideone.com/iTVMW

Answer (score 2):

PHP arrays work this way by default.

```
$arr = array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4);
var_dump($arr); // 1, 2, 3, 4

unset($arr['three']);
var_dump($arr); // 1, 2, 4

$arr['five'] = 5;
var_dump($arr); // 1, 2, 4, 5
```